# TextWatcher not detecting delete key

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a TextWatcher that places a percent sign after numbers in an EditText.  That part works fine.  The problem is if the user makes a mistake and needs to delete the numbers in the editText, the percent sign does not allow any deletions. below is my code:

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            String originalString = s.toString();

            if (originalString.contains("%")) {
                originalString = originalString.replaceAll("%", "");

            }

            String formattedString = originalString + "%";

            //setting text after format to EditText
            editText.setText(formattedString);
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }


    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);


}
```

I believe I need an OnKeyListener but don't know exactly how to implement it.  this is what I did with the OnKeyListener but it doesn't work:

```
boolean keyDelete

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if(!keyDelete) {

        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            String originalString = s.toString();

            if (originalString.contains("%")) {
                originalString = originalString.replaceAll("%", "");

            }

            String formattedString = originalString + "%";

            //setting text after format to EditText
                editText.setText(formattedString);
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());

            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                nfe.printStackTrace();
            }

            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
            keyDelete = true;
        }else{
            keyDelete = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated..

Comment: try removing this `editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh just tried that and it brings the cursor to the beginning of the editText field

Comment: user can't change the cursor position and delete a number?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh they can change the position of the cursor but I would like the percent sign to be deleted if user made an error

Comment: how about if you try  `if(formattedString.length()>=1){editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1);}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if a user sets a cursor before '%' symbol. The issue is that after text formatting you set selection to the end of a text.

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

In a case, when a user pushes the delete button without replacing a cursor, he is deleting '%' symbol, but your code returns '%' symbol back each time. This is because feels like:

> the percent sign does not allow any deletions

To solve your issue refactor your code to set selections before '%' symbol:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    try {
        String originalString = s.toString();

        if (originalString.contains("%")) {
            originalString = originalString.replaceAll("%", "");

        }

        String formattedString = originalString + "%";

        //setting text after format to EditText
        editText.setText(formattedString);
        if (formattedString.length() >= 1) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - 1);
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }


    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```